# Using a conditions hash in a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

Here's my models:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :landlord

  has_one :landlord_user, through: :landlord, :source => :user
  delegate :last_sign_in_at, to: :landlord_user, prefix: 'landlord'

  has_many :tickets_created_since_last_landlord_login, class_name: 'Ticket', conditions: lambda {"created_at > #{landlord_last_sign_in_at}" }

end
```

However, any time I try to use the association it returns the following:

```
property.tickets_created_since_last_landlord_login => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy>
```

which is not what I expected, and if I try to load the association:

```
property.tickets_created_since_last_landlord_login.all =>  ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

on the `tickets_created_since_landlord_last_signed_in` association definition.

Can anybody offer an explanation as to why this isn't working?  I'm stumped.

Comment: hmm, syntax errors abound. no way you're getting past syntax errors based on what you've posted.  can you update and post the exact code you're running?